# In ggplot2, how can I use multi-row x-axis labels with facet_wraps?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have multi-row x-axis labels such that the first row is month and the second row is year. However, I run into `check_aesthetics()` errors when I try to use the multi-row axis labels with `facet_wrap()`.

Example Data:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 12))
colnames(df1)[1:3] <- c("Date", "Group", "Value")
df1$Date <- rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2020-03-14"),as.Date("2020-08-20"),"1 month"),2)
df1$Group <- sort(rep(c("A","B"),6))
df1$Value <- rnorm(12,50,10)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(Month = month(Date),
         Year = year(Date),
         date = zoo::as.yearmon(paste(Year, Month), "%Y %m"))

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 12))
colnames(df2)[1:3] <- c("Date", "Group", "Value")
df2$Date <- rep(seq.Date(as.Date("2021-03-14"),as.Date("2021-08-20"),"1 month"),2)
df2$Group <- sort(rep(c("A","B"),6))
df2$Value <- rnorm(12,50,10)
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Month = month(Date),
         Year = year(Date),
         date = zoo::as.yearmon(paste(Year, Month), "%Y %m"))

df3 <- rbind(df1,df2)

cols <- c("A" = "#ca0020", "B" = "#0571b0")
```

Figure without `facet_wrap()` showing the multi-row x-axis

```
ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = factor(date), y = Value, color = Group, group = paste(Year,Group))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(fill = Group), color = "black", shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=substr(df3$date,1,3))+
  labs(x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 2, 1), "lines"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.margin = margin(),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.1,0.93),
        panel.border = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off', ylim = c(0, 100)) +
  annotation_custom(grid::rectGrob(gp = grid::gpar(fill = NA))) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = c(3.5,9.5), y = -15, label = unique(df3$Year), size = 6) +
  annotate('rect',
           xmin = 6.35,
           xmax = 6.65,
           ymin = -10, ymax = 0, fill = 'white') +
  annotate('segment',
           x = c(6.35, 6.65),
           xend = c(6.35, 6.65), y = -10, yend = 0)
```

Now when I try to add the `facet_wrap()`...

```
ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = factor(date), y = Value, color = Group, group = paste(Year,Group))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(fill = Group), color = "black", shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=substr(df3$date,1,3))+
  labs(x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 2, 1), "lines"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.margin = margin(),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.1,0.93),
        panel.border = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off', ylim = c(0, 100)) +
  annotation_custom(grid::rectGrob(gp = grid::gpar(fill = NA))) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = c(3.5,9.5), y = -15, label = unique(df3$Year), size = 6) +
  annotate('rect',
           xmin = 6.35,
           xmax = 6.65,
           ymin = -10, ymax = 0, fill = 'white') +
  annotate('segment',
           x = c(6.35, 6.65),
           xend = c(6.35, 6.65), y = -10, yend = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~Group)
```

...it throws the error `` Error in `check_aesthetics()`: ! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): label ``.

The error resides within `annotate(geom = "text", x = c(3.5,9.5), y = -15, label = unique(df3$Year), size = 6) +` but I can't figure out how to fix it. I have tried changing the `label =`  and the `x =`  but no luck. The ideal figure would have two plots, each with multi-row x-axis labels where, similar to the example figure above, the top row is month and the second row is year. Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One kind of hacky way to do this is to just make two text annotations

```
ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = factor(date), y = Value, color = Group, group = paste(Year,Group))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(fill = Group), color = "black", shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=substr(df3$date,1,3))+
  labs(x = "") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 2, 1), "lines"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.margin = margin(),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.1,0.93),
        panel.border = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off', ylim = c(0, 100)) +
  annotation_custom(grid::rectGrob(gp = grid::gpar(fill = NA))) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = c(3.5), y = -15, label = 2020, size = 6) +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = c(9.5), y = -15, label = 2021, size = 6) +
  annotate('rect',
           xmin = 6.35,
           xmax = 6.65,
           ymin = -10, ymax = 0, fill = 'white') +
  annotate('segment',
           x = c(6.35, 6.65),
           xend = c(6.35, 6.65), y = -10, yend = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~Group)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind moving the year value to the strip you could use `ggh4x` package.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(ggh4x)

ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = factor(date), y = Value, color = Group, group = paste(Year,Group))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 3, aes(fill = Group), color = "black", shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_color_manual(values = cols) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=substr(df3$date,1,3))+
  labs(x = NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 2, 1), "lines"),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        text = element_text(size = 16),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, color = "black", angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, color = "black"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.margin = margin(),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.1,0.90),
        panel.border = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2)) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off', ylim = c(0, 100)) +
  facet_nested(~Group + Year, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>